# Why does Vanessa Paradis do budget indie films?

Tags: production

Her net worth is 150 million and she does movies that has no budget at all, e.g. throughout 2017 she did 3 films and all indie.

You can see her profile:
https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0660854/

I just watched https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6464290/ and it's really boring and bad, a no-budget and it aired on TV. It's just one of the examples.

I don't think she even gets paid, because you couldn't afford it. And doesn't seem like she's doing it for any money.

So anyone know why she does festival movies only with no budget? I thought it's something deep and artistic, films that do not aim for profit, but those are just really bad, like I said Frost (2017) is really bad writing and acting and everything else.

Help me connect the dots, how unknown studios and directors get someone with $150 million budget to shoot in their movie with no money that can't even afford to release it to DVD?

Answer (score 5):

The most likely explanation for this has two major components:

1. **She has different tastes in movies from you**. Just because you didn't like any of those movies doesn't me that she doesn't love them. They might be her three favorite movies ever made, for all we know.
2. **Acting in a movie is very different from watching that movie**. There are many reasons to act in a movie that have nothing to do with money. She might have been able to do a different kind of acting or play a different kind of part from how she is usually cast. She may have been able to work with a director and/or other actors that she has always wanted to work with. She might have been helping out a friend. And the process of making a movie can be very rewarding even if the end results aren't so good. It's often said that we learn from our mistakes. Even if she doesn't like these movies herself, she is learning how it feels to be on the set and work with a director who is in the process of making a bad movie. It's very hard to tell when working on a project how other people will see it. I would say you can only learn what making a bad film is like by doing it.

Her perspective is more likely to be that since she has earned $150 million making one movie, she now has the money to live on while she goes to make some movies that seem really fun for her that don't pay as much. The vast majority of people who work in the entertainment industry got into it to have *fun*. If I had $100 million in my bank account you better believe I would go goof off with my friends and make some music that I like and make some silly films that I think are fun even if everyone else hates them.